# Wired headphone buttons on Windows

Tags: audio, windows-8.1, headphones, media-keys

I got a new, shiny pair of Sony MDR-10R headphones and the detachable cable comes with a Play/Pause button. Is there any way to make Windows (or any media player in Windows) recognize these button?

Answer (score 0):

I know that most new laptops recognize the standard media buttons on headphones. IF they have the 4 pin connector, i.e. they have a mic as well, you should be fine. you might need an adapter from the 4 pin connector to 2 3 pin connectors if your laptop has separate mic and headphone jacks.

Comment: It has the 4 section connector so I'll need an adapter. Now how do I make my player payse/play when pussing the button? Does this depend on Windows or my player of choice?

Comment: I would think that it would be coded into at least windows media player if not received as a general play/pause code by the OS. I know that I can just plug my headphones into my mac and it does the play/pause in any media application. If your computer supports media remotes, it should work fine. The play pause button works by way of sending a specific signal into the mic port, sometimes i am able to hear it as a slight click, so that is why you need a mic port.